# Java Swing More efficient event broadcasting

Tags: java, swing

I want to be able to have a canvas component that adds spots to places where the user double clicks, when a spot is added, and then I want to be able to notify the listbox placed in the main frame that a spot has been added. 
My knowledge of event broadcasting is poor, is there a better way of doing this?

Main class: initialize drawing component:
will this be best for an unnamed inner class?

```
private JList lbx;
private DefaultListModel<String> lbxModel;
private DrawComp draw;
public static void main(String args[]) {
draw.addListener(new DrawCompListener() {

            @Override
            public void spotAdded(DrawComp source, Spot spot) {
                lbxModel.addElement("spot+" added");
            }
        });
}
```

interface that will be passed through to the queue:

```
public interface DrawCompListener {
    void spotAdded(DrawComp source, Spot spot);
```

Queue Class that will implement the interface: (should this be here?)

```
public class DrawCompListenerQueue implements DrawCompListener {
    private ArrayList<DrawCompListener> listeners = new ArrayList<DrawCompListener>();

    public void addListener(DrawCompListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
@Override
    public void spotAdded(DrawComp source, Spot spot) {
        for(DrawCompListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.spotAdded(source, spot);
        }
    }
```

The actual drawing component to place the spots and pass through the info to the main class for the Jlist

```
public class DrawComp extends JPanel implements MouseListener {     
    private Vector<Spot> spots = new Vector<Spot>();    
    private DrawCompListenerQueue listenerQ = new DrawCompListenerQueue();    
    public void addListener(DrawCompListener listener) {
        listenerQ.addListener(listener);
    }
```

adding a spot:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // left-click = add spot
        if ((e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) && (e.getClickCount() == 2)) {
            // add spot
            Spot s = new Spot();
            s.p = e.getPoint();
            spots.add(s);
            repaint();

            // notify listeners
            listenerQ.spotAdded(this, s);
```

Comment: The question is, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel use the [Glazed list](http://www.glazedlists.com/) lib.